What evolutionary pressures would cause the majority of animals to only have one eye?
On Earth, most animals with eyes have binocular vision for a variety of reasons. But assuming an Earthlike world in which multicellular life with the PAX6 gene evolves under similar conditions to the origin of our own living creatures, under what environmental circumstances would most of these organisms only have a single eye? Assume the described world has the same environments, gravity, magnetic field, and available elements as Earth.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Doubt there is any. One eye is too easy to lose, and should you not need any eyes, just have no eyes, less prone to damage.

"Most animals have binocular vision": If this is supposed to mean that most animals have exactly two eyes, this affirmation definitely needs a citation. There are lots and lots of animal species with zero eyes, one eye, or more than two eyes. I would not even attempt to estimate whether there are more species with exactly two eyes than species with zero, one, or more than two eyes.

@AlexP The only taxon of monocular animals I could find when researching this question myself was the genus Cyclops, or water fleas. And by saying binocular vision, I imply that the animals I’m talking about already have some number of eyes to begin with.

You may add our good friend the lancelet, and of course the nauplius larval stage of most crustaceans.

Yes, that may be true, but compare that number to every binocular animal you can think of. It doesn’t seem to be a necessary citation or clarification in my mind.

I can't help but feel that this question has conflicting requirements. The only cases I can imagine where binocular vision would be a genetic negative are cases where the environment is 2-dimensional, and I don't see that cropping up in an Earth-like world, much less being the dominant environment. Also, this question feels very brainstorm prone, looking for a way to justify an impossible situation.

@Jobah619 Binocular vision does not mean what you appear to think it does, a great many animals that have two eyes do not have binocular vision, rabbits being a classic example, I think you may need to check the dictionary.


under what environmental circumstances would most of these organisms only have a single eye?

Take out the evolution of the ancestors of bilaterally symmetrical animals. Animals didn't evolve two eyes for binocular vision, many animals with two eyes don't have binocular vision. The first animals had no eyes at all, then came light sensitive patches of skin, and eventually many different sorts of eyes.
So in your case if there was radial symmetry as the early ancestor and a central eye clump or light sensitive area then all it's descendants could have one eye. Or asymmetrical symmetry with just one light sensitive region.

If you have no predators and easy access to food, mating becomes the focus
Binocular vision is great to spot predators and prey. If you don't have those problems, it is conceivable you species will not evolve to have 2+ eyes.
Add a mating ritual to your species like the peacock, then you can explain that the males with the biggest, most centered eye are more often selected for mating. In this scenario, the prominence of the single eye evolves to attract the females of the species.
This question has an answer here: Benefits of or reasons why a species would have only one eye?
